Getting an 'ImportError' when packaging a Cython extension
Been trying to solve this error for a while. I'm working on a package named mlsauce. When I clone the package and run python3 -m pip install . --verbose (in a virtual environment), I get Successfully installed mlsauce-0.17.1. HOWEVER at runtime, I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/codespaces-blank/mlsauce/examples/adaopt_classifier.py", line 13, in <module>
    import mlsauce as ms
  File "/workspaces/codespaces-blank/mlsauce/mlsauce/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .adaopt import AdaOpt
  File "/workspaces/codespaces-blank/mlsauce/mlsauce/adaopt/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .adaopt import AdaOpt
  File "/workspaces/codespaces-blank/mlsauce/mlsauce/adaopt/adaopt.py", line 11, in <module>
    import adaoptc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adaoptc'

I can see the .so file in the repository though:
Repository's tree structure
How can I solve this error?

do you use Python 3.10? Because this .so is for 3.10 and other python may need .so with different name

do you use Linux? Because this .so is for Linux and may not work with other systems.

@furas I use both Linux (Ubuntu) and macOS and Python >= 3.9. But it doesn't matter here, since setup.py compiles the extension regardless of the platform

you could check source code for adaopt.py to see how it works - maybe there is some mistake. And maybe it would need to send issue to author(s) of this module.

@furas I am the author

Imported the extension exactly as in https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#cython-hello-world
